# Wake Up PC from Hibernate state

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hibernate, dell-studio

Is there a way to set a specified time for Wake Up of PC while it is Hibernated state. I want this feature in Windows 7, running in Dell Studio 1555 laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Use Freware: [WakeupOnStandBy](http://dennisbabkin.com/wosb/), [SmartPower](http://ignatu.co.uk/SmartPower.aspx)

Prop: [Auto Power on & Shut down](http://www.lifsoft.com/index.html)

Windows Task Scheduler:

[How to Change the Return to Sleep Timeout for a Unattended Wake Up in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/171042-sleep-return-timeout-unattended-wake-up.html)

[How to Troubleshoot a Vista or Windows 7 Sleep Mode Problem](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/63567-power-options-sleep-mode-problems.html)

[How to Create a Task to Wake up the Computer to Run in Vista and Windows 7](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/166809-task-scheduler-wake-up-computer.html)

[How to Disable or Enable Password Protection on Wake Up in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/102686-password-protection-wakeup.html)

WOL, Wake on Line: